# Complete metrizability of some disconnected spaces.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

(1) Is the [Knaster-Kuratowski fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan)
 minus its vertex completely metrizable? (SOLVED by Alex)

(2) I see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=k5_-CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=hereditarily%20disconnected%20but%20not%20totally%20disconnected&source=bl&ots=XweieELlmI&sig=ZK6DBIcVbn78oqybk5PReZ300Qs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS4JWSiuzJAhXIMSYKHecPD5YQ6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q=hereditarily%20disconnected%20but%20not%20totally%20disconnected&f=false) (see middle paragraph 'Sierpinski [1922]'), that there is a space with similar properties to the K-K fan, that is completely metrizable.  I believe it is the space I recently explained here: [Exercise in Engelking's book regarding a disconnected space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585108/exercise-in-engelkings-book-regarding-a-disconnected-space). Why is it completely metrizable?

**Edit:** We want to show that the space $X_1$ (click link to my other post, above, under (2)) is completely metrizable. Here's all I know at this point:

(i) $g[X]$ is actually homeomorphic to $X$, the set of rational points in the Hilbert space.

(ii) As $g[X]$ is open in $X_1$, we know $g[X]$ cannot be complete in any metric we put on $X_1$. All non-convergent Cauchy sequences in $g[X]$ would have to converge to the added point $\{(0,1/2)\}$.  Maybe this observation will help to define the complete metric.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the following.

(1). No. Let $X$ be a  Knaster-Kuratowski fan minus its vertex. Let $c\in C$ be an arbitrary endpoint of an interval deleted in the Cantor set. If $X$ is completely metrizable then  a set $X_c\setminus \{p\}$ is a countable closed subspace of $X$ (and hence Baire) without isolated points, which is impossible

(2) The space $X$ is *not* completely metrizable by similar reasons. It contains a countable closed subspace $\{(x_1,0,\dots,0):x_1\in\Bbb Q\}$ without isolated points.

Comment: +1 for the first part of your answer.  As for part (2), I want to look at the space $X_1$ mentioned in my other post, not $X$ (although it is good to know $X$ is not c.m.).

Comment: @ForeverMozart I'm afraid that it may be easier to find an other completely metrizable space with similar properties to the K-K fan than to show that the space $X_1$ is completely metrizable.